# Not able to call a class's member function in other class in the same assembly

Tags: c#, scope

I am not able to call the member function of a class in another by creating an instance of the former(all in the same assembly). Kindly help.

```
namespace MovieListCaseStudy
{    
   class BusinessLogic
   {
        List<Movie> movielist = new List<Movie>()
        {
            new Movie {Id=1, Name="pk", Duration=2, Price=200}            
        };

        Movie searchMovie(int id)
        {
            Movie result = null;
            foreach( Movie m in movielist)
            {
                if(id==m.Id)
                {
                    result = m;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }            
    }        
}
```

---

```
namespace MovieListCaseStudy
{    
    class UserInterface    
    {           
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BusinessLogic bl = new BusinessLogic();
            bl //Not able to access the method _searchMovie_ here                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Default access modifier is `private`. Change it to `public`.

Answer (score 3):

Add access modifiers to the members of `BusinessLogic`. All members are implicitly`private`; they must be explicitly `internal` or `public` to be accesssed from another class (unless nesting classes is somehow involved.)

Answer (score 0):

Your method is `private`, you need to make it `public`.

```
public Movie searchMovie(int id)
```

> The access level for class members and struct members, including nested classes and structs, **is private by default**.

Read more about access modifiers here:

- [Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

Comment: But isn't **internal** the default access specifier in c# which makes it accessible in the same namespace?

Answer (score 0):

The default modifier for class members are `private`. Make your method public:

```
public Movie searchMovie(int id)
    {
      ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant call it because you must declare it as `public`